# Representation-preserving isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

Suppose we have two algebraic groups $G,H$ over a field $K$ (maybe reductive) and we know in advance that $G(A)\cong H(A)$ for some $K$-algebra A. If we attach algebraic representations $\rho_{G(A)}, \rho_{H(A)}$ (over the same vector space) to them then is there necessarily a way to construct such an isomorphism that preserves the representations?

i.e. can we find an isomorphism $\phi: G(A) \longrightarrow H(A)$ such that $\rho_{H(A)}(\phi(g)) = \rho_{G(A)}(g)$

How about just for $1$-dimensional representations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer (ie, with example): Let $G = H = GL_n$ and let $A = K$ (or some extension of $K$ if $|K| = 2$).
Let $\rho_{G(A)}$ be the determinant, and let $\rho_{H(A)}$ be the trivial 1-dimensional representation.

Now no such isomorphism can exist, as $\rho_{H(A)}(g) = 1$ for all $g$, and this is not the case for $\rho_{G(A)}$.

Comment: Of course, how stupid of me! Is there a restriction on the representations that forces it to be true? My main interest is what happens for quaternion algebras and certain algebraic groups over those. For example if $D$ is a quaternion algebra that becomes split over $K$ then one can always choose an isomorphism $D^{\times} \cong \text{GL}_2(K)$ such that norm <-> det is respected. Similarly with $\text{GL}_n(D) \cong \text{GL}_{2n}(K)$ and even $\text{GU}_n(D) \cong \text{GSp}_{2n}(K)$ respecting similitude reps on both sides.

Comment: I know very little of algebraic groups if you allow non-commutative algebras (I don't think those would usually even be called algebraic groups).

Comment: I had this problem too, but many papers seem to refer to these as algebraic groups.

Comment: @fretty Interesting. Could you give an example of such (or just some author names)? I am only familiar with algebraic groups as treated in Jantzen's book.

Comment: See any paper on the Jacquet-Langlands correspondence. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacquet%E2%80%93Langlands_correspondence

Comment: Automorphic forms are attached to (reductive) algebraic groups so here it is readily claimed that GL$_n(D)$ is an algebraic group.